# Snowpark using Jupyter (Connectivity)

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to execute the script below in Juypiter using Snowpark, but it is throwing an error.

My Snowflake URL: https://lobpvaq-ap14662.snowflakecomputing.com/

**Current Python Session Details:**

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

**Output:**

3.8.10

**Script to connect snowflake:**

```
from snowflake.snowpark import Session

connection_parameters = {

    "account":'lobpvaq-ap14662',

    "user":'XXXXX' ,

    "password":'XXXXX'
}

test_session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
```

Error Message:

> OperationalError: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting

Please help me, I am not sure where I am making a mistake.

Thanks

Comment: are you able to connect using `snowsql` with the same credential info?

Comment: It almost looks like there is no network connectivity between your Jupyter and Snowflake account.  Are you able to use the browser and connect to the account? Do you have any proxy set?